# How to allow accented characters(UTF-8 supported) characters in TO and FROM of an email?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I want to send mail with accented characters from spanish and french.I am able to send with the below code

```
  SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage(simpleMailMessage);
    message.setTo(emailAddress);
    message.setText(bodyContent);
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setFrom(fromMail);

    try {
        mailSender.send(message);
    } catch (MailException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But when i try to send mail with accented characters (nÄrendra_pandeyñõ@abc.com) in FROM and TO field it gives following error

> javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Local address contains control or    >whitespace in string ``närendra_pandeyñõ@abc.com''

Answer (score 0):

Use the [InternetAddress contructor that takes separate personal name and email address parameters](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#InternetAddress-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).